# Laravel calcinai/xero-php openssl_pkey_get_private returned false error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, private-key, xero-api

I have integrated `calcinai/xero-php` for `xero` **Invoice API** in **Laravel 5.8**.

But it is throwing me below error:

> Cannot access private key for signing:
>   openssl_pkey_get_private('file://storage/certs/private.pem') returned false

What is the problem?